# How to block specific internet connections using react-native

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, ethernet

How I can block specific Ethernet connections using react-native?
My idea is to build an app that will get a whitelist of sites, and the app blocks the rest of the connections.

Comment: Why don't you just use Regex to allow the whitelist sites and reject all others?